# Inner select makes slidedown div (parent) disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this dropdown (slidedown) that has a `select` element inside it:

http://jsfiddle.net/XFNhU/1/

On **Chrome** you can show it and then select from 1-4 (2-4, you click the box hides) so working 50%.

On **FF** if you show the box and hover over an option it immediately disappears.

I have tried this:

```
function display(".drop") {
    document.getElementsByClassName(".drop").style.left = "-5px";
}

function hide(".drop") {
    document.getElementsByClassName(".drop").style.left = "-9999px";
}
```

...but to no avail. Wondering if anyone knew how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an extra event handler just for the `select` element that [stops the event propagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) from bubbling up the DOM.

This way the second callback function for the hover event on `$('header .parent.animated')` doesn't get called if the cursor is still over the `select` element:

```
$('header .parent.animated select').hover(
    function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    },
    function(){
        $(this).parents('.drop').hide();
    }
);
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/XFNhU/8/

This seems to work in both Chrome and Firefox.